# Best practice for CSS/HTML Layouts - Div's or Semantic HTML?

Tags: css, html

When creating HTML layouts should I use:

- DIV classes and ID's
- Semantic HTML5
- Blend of both?

Comment: Check out (http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/). Read the discussion below the article.

Comment: It really depends on the context of the project, as described by @Pharao2k. For example, I've done legacy work before (for IE8 and below) where I stuck to using nothing but <div>, <span>, etc because the semantic markup was never going to work as it should.

Comment: For layouts, you should use CSS. You use HTML to convey content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantic HTML5 is preferred, but it depends on your targeted scenario and type of homepage/application.

A more specific answer can be given if you clarify your question a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really just trying to understand best practice on a new build.